Source of Galileo quote on curves
In George Simmons' Calculus Gems there is an interesting quote, supposedly from Galileo, pertaining to whether one can compare curved and straight lines (in length, for instance):

Who is so blind as not to see that, if there are two equal straight lines, one of which is then bent into a curve, that curve will be equal to the straight line?

In the context of the book, this seems to be in response to La Géométrie, but Simmons also likes telling good stories, so perhaps this is a separate quote - or perhaps it's apocryphal, or maybe it's just not in a well-known source.
In any case, any tips as to what dialogue/letter this is from would be greatly appreciated.

I do not think a "response": Descartes' Geometrie was published in 1637, only five years before Galileo death.

This is a bit odd because Simmons says that the occasion was Torricelli's computation of the length of the logarithmic spiral. However, Descartes's opinion that "ratios between straight and curved lines are not known, and... cannot be discovered" concerned algebraic curves and not curves generated by motions like the spiral. He did not doubt that bending a string would preserve its length, he objected to curves obtained by such bending as "non-geometrical", see Mancosu and Crippa.

@Conifold, This is a bit odd because the common wisdom seems to be that Descartes viewed only algebraic curves as the domain of geometry, and on the contrary viewed mechanically-produced ones as lying outside that domain, so it should be the opposite...  Leibniz famously challenged Descartes' assumption in this area.

Thanks for the clarifications on Descartes' views re: mechanical versus algebraic curves. (And I suspected as much about the timing, though Simmons is vague on the point.)  So ... do people that this purported quote is apocryphal?  I can't imagine Simmons inventing it completely from whole cloth, given that he does cite a fair number of his stories, but maybe something got garbled along the way?

I actually came across this exact passage last year.  I'm surprised I remembered it!
Simmons appears to be borrowing from Drabkin's translation of Galileo's De motu as the passage is word for word the same.  Specifically, this is in the book Galileo Galilei On Motion and On Mechanics, which is a translation of De motu [On Motion] and Le meccaniche [On Mechanics], respectively by I.E. Drabkin and Stillman Drake, p. 71.  It is the last passage of Ch. [15] titled "In which, in opposition to Aristotle, the conclusion is reached that rectilinear and circular motions have a ratio to each other."  The entire last paragraph is reproduced below:

Furthermore, who is so blind as not to see that, if there are two
equal straight lines, one of which is then bent into a curve, that
curve will be equal to the straight line? Or if a circle moves over a
straight line, who will doubt that in one revolution it traverses a
straight line equal to its circumference? Let us then have no doubts
that there exists a rectilinear motion equal to a given curvilinear
motion, and also rectilinear motion bearing to curvilinear motion any
given ratio.

A few other things to bear in mind. Galileo wrote his De motu around 1589-1592, however, he never published it. It predates La Géométrie (1637), so the quote is not in response to it.  Much later, portions of the De motu were first published in 1854 in Volume 11 of Eugenio Albèri’s edition of Galileo’s works, and the remaining portions were published in 1883 by Antonio Favaro. The manuscript was later published under the title De Motu in volume I of the National Edition of the works of Galileo, edited in 1890 by Favaro, which contained certain manuscripts written in Latin in Galileo’s own hand. The first and only English translation of the essay portion of De Motu translated by I. E. Drabkin was published in 1960 under the title On Motion and On Mechanics, which was included alongside Stillman Drake's translation of Galileo's Le Meccaniche.
